# How to make a RF Choke?

Tags: inductor, receiver, frequency-modulation, choke

I am a high school student and am making a project on FM receiver for class 11. I am following this circuit diagram:

[image: Schematic]

The L2 in this diagram is a 22µH RF Choke. The part listed in the [website](http://www.somerset.net/arm/fm_only_one_transistor_radio.html) has the configuration provided below in its [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/54/70f_series-62652.pdf).

```
L= 22uH +/-5%
Q= 51
Test Freq.= 2.5 MHz
SRF= 13
DCR Max.=2.28 Ohm
I, DC= 229 mA
Dim. A Max.= 0.16 inch
Dim. B +/-0.03= 0.25 inch
Core Material= iron
```

I know how to make inductors but some properties such as the thickness of the copper wire (in SWG), whether enameled or not, no. of turns to use and the diameter and length of the inductor is confusing me.

And as an additional note can u please mention the number of turns in the L1 and the thickness of the copper wire to be used that will be suitable for the circuit diagram.

Comment: It depends on the properties of the core you are using.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just purchase a suitable one from digi-key or some other supplier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since coil winding data is not provided for L2 the obvious solution is to just buy one. But if you insist on making your own...

According to [this site](http://web.archive.org/web/20070902112405/http://braincambre500.freeservers.com/rss%281%29%281%29%281%29.htm#ac), it should be made from 26 turns of 30 gauge enameled magnet wire, close-wound around an 8mm nonmetallic (ie. "air core") cylindrical form.

[image: Source Coil 1]
[image: Source Coil 2]

Now let's see if we can figure out the inductance of this coil. We will use an approximation of [Harold Wheeler's formula](http://electronbunker.ca/CalcMethods3b.html) for the inductance of a single layer air core solenoid:-

L (uH) = r^2 * n^2 / (9 * r + 10 * l)

where r = coil radius in inches, l = coil length in inches, and n = number of turns.

But we don't know the length! However we do know that it is 26 times the diameter of a single wire. Bare 30AWG wire has a diameter of 0.01 inches, but enameling may add 10~20% depending on the type of coating. Assuming the coating increases diameter to 0.012 inches, the coil should be about 0.312 inches long.

Now convert the form diameter of 8mm to inches, add wire thickness to get coil diameter (0.327 inches), plug all the numbers into [a calculator](http://www.66pacific.com/calculators/coil_calc.aspx) and what do we get? 3.9uH! Seems a bit low, but apparently the circuits works with this value.

Next: how to make your own capacitors, resistors, semiconductors...

Answer (score 1):

For a given number of turns: increasing diameter increases inductance (more wire interacting with itself). Increasing length reduces inductance (more distance between the wires).
For a given length and diameter: increasing the number of turns increases inductance (more wire again)

Then there is the core material. Your data sheet specifies an **Iron** core. I used the calculator [here](http://detrickmartin.net/coil//) to come up with 14 turn of 22AWG on a 10mm diameter iron core.
If you are keen to do this yourself, I suggest find an iron core first, measure the diameter, then fiddle with number of turns etc. until you get a close fit. For an FM receiver, if all you are doing is choking high frequencies, there is plenty of room for a "close enough" value.